# "TypeError: _reactTestRenderer.default.act is not a function" despite same React and react-test-renderer version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-testing-library

I'm very new to React and am trying to integrate a unit test framework into an existing React-redux application. I've got the following test to test a 'Cancel' button:

```
import React from 'react';
import DependencySystemCreatePage from "../../_components/dependencySys/DependencySystemCreatePage";
import {depSysCreateProps, depSysCreateContext, depSysCreateState} from "./TestConstants";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import configureStore from "redux-mock-store";
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

const mockStore = configureStore();

test("Test Cancel button", () => {
  let store = mockStore(depSysCreateState);
  store.dispatch = jest.fn();

  let component = renderer.create(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <DependencySystemCreatePage {...depSysCreateProps} />
    </Provider>
  )

  expect(component.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();

  renderer.act(() => {
    component.root.findByType('button').props.onClick();
  });
  expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

})
```

To which I get the following error:

```
TypeError: _reactTestRenderer.default.act is not a function
      24 |   expect(component.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
      25 |
    > 26 |   renderer.act(() => {
         |            ^
      27 |     component.root.findByType('button').props.onClick();
      28 |   });
      29 |   expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

In case it helps, my react, react-dom and react-test-renderer versions are all 15.4.0 and jest is 29.6.4. I understand that most existing online solutions to this issue suggest that react, react-dom and react-test-renderer all be the same version, which I have, but I'm still running into this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You'll probably want `import * as renderer from 'react-test-renderer';` or `import {act} from 'react-test-renderer';`.

Comment: Did that and now I get `TypeError: renderer.act is not a function`. Any idea why JS doesnt recognize renderer.act as a function?